# PHP Laravel : Ajax couldn't retrieve data (No properties)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a laravel application where I want to generate some report with ajax controller. With the same raw query in MySQL I can see the data but using ajax I couldn't show in my view page.
in console it's showing `[] No Properties`

[image]

I'm not getting why it's showing the above Error. If anyone find what's the wrong, please help me to find it out.Thanks.

Here is the controller I have used for retrieving the data from database:

```
  public function ajax_view_schedule(Request $request)
    {

          $dept_id= $request->Input(['dept_id']);
$schedule= DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT courses.code as c_code, courses.name as c_name,COALESCE( CONCAT('R. No',':',rooms.room_number,', ',days.name ,', ', allocate_rooms.start,' - ',allocate_rooms.end),'Not Scheduled Yet') AS schedule
FROM departments join courses on departments.id = courses.department_id
left join allocate_rooms on allocate_rooms.course_id=courses.id 
left join rooms on allocate_rooms.room_id=rooms.id
left join days on allocate_rooms.day_id=days.id WHERE departments.id='.$dept_id.'"));
        return \Response::json($schedule);  
    }
```

And here is the view page with ajax code:

```
<div class="container" >
        <h3> View Class Schedule and Room Allocation Information </h3>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">Department</label>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" required id="department" name="department_id" >
        <option>Select a Department</option>
        @foreach($department as $row)
        <option value="{{$row->id}}">{{$row->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>   



    <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered"  id="example">
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <td>Course Code</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Schedule Info</td>                      
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

   </tbody>
    </table>        
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $('#department').on('change',function(e){               
       var dept_id = $('#department option:selected').attr('value');

      $.ajaxSetup({
                  headers: {
                      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                  });

               $.ajax({ 
                  type: "POST", 
                  url : "{{url('ajax-view-schedule')}}",
                  data:{dept_id:dept_id},
                success : function(data) { 
                      var $tbody = $('#example tbody').empty();                  
                    $.each(data,function(index,subcatObj){                    
                    $tbody.append('<tr><td class="code">' + subcatObj.c_code + '</td><td class="course_name">' + subcatObj.c_name + '</td><td class="schedule">' + subcatObj.schedule + '</td></tr>');
                        });
                     } 
              });     
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you post the developer tools net panel screenshot?

Comment: what do you see when you navigate to website.url/ajax-view-schedule ,?

Comment: I have upload the screenshot and that's my view page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually in double quotes so php will interpolate your variable

```
  public function ajax_view_schedule(Request $request)
    {

          $dept_id= $request->Input(['dept_id']);
$schedule= DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT courses.code as c_code, courses.name as c_name,COALESCE( CONCAT('R. No',':',rooms.room_number,', ',days.name ,', ', allocate_rooms.start,' - ',allocate_rooms.end),'Not Scheduled Yet') AS schedule
FROM departments join courses on departments.id = courses.department_id
left join allocate_rooms on allocate_rooms.course_id=courses.id 
left join rooms on allocate_rooms.room_id=rooms.id
left join days on allocate_rooms.day_id=days.id WHERE departments.id='$dept_id'"));//remove dot from .$dept_id.
        return \Response::json($schedule);  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. got the mistake! :)